# Wordpress - displaying different pages depending on user

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WooCommerce to build a e-commerce website. The business broadly has a few different types of users to get a variety of tasks done. The types are given below;

1) Administrators
2) Distributors
3) Customers

I could achieve the above with the given pre built user types that woocommerce provides.

What i aim to do is to display specific pages depending on who is signed in. Obviously, the three have their own tasks that they need to carry out on the website.

Here for example, I would want the Administrators to view a few extra page in the menu bar.

where as, customers will have their shopping catalogue to view and carry out their checking out experience as built with woocommerce.

I have had a look around different plugins that could possibly achieve this, but couldn't find any yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this task. One way would be to create a page and a page template, that redirects to another page, based on the user's role. Then those pages could re-direct if a user of an invalid role tried to access them. So the *do_somthing.php* page could redirect to the *admin_do_somthing.php*, *distributors_do_somthing.php* and *customers_do_somthing.php*, and each of those 3 would throw and error or re-direct to the home page if accessed by a user, or anonymous HTTP request, with a different role.

**Keywords** to lookup: "**Worpress pages**" "**Wordpress templates**" "**Wordpress user roles**" "**wp_redirect()**"